# Problema de syntaxis en un Update que usa varias tablas MySql

Tags: mysql, update

tengo problemas para actualizar los gastos de un usuario, a continuación explico la estructura del problema.

```
// Tabla con datos de usuario
CREATE TABLE `Usuarios` (
  `correo` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `a_paterno` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contrasena` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `celular` int(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `salario` double DEFAULT NULL
)

// Tabla que relaciona a los usuarios con sus gastos
CREATE TABLE `Tiene_gasto` (
  `id_gasto` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `correo_u` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL
)

//Tabla con todos los gastos del sistema
CREATE TABLE `Gastos` (
  `fecha` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_gasto` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `monto` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `nombre_cat` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

Juan, uno de los usuarios, desea actualizar el tipo de cambio de todos sus gastos.
Para ello necesito multiplicar toda la columna 'monto' de la tabla 'Gastos' por el tipo de cambio (pesos mexicanos / dolares americanos)
19.39 / 1, pero exclusivamente aquellos gastos pertenecientes a Juan.
Estoy intentando hacer un Update a toda la columna de una tabla que solo contiene los gastos de Juan.

```
UPDATE Usuarios SET moneda = 'MXN' WHERE correo = 'juan@lol';

UPDATE dummy
SET Gast.monto = monto/ 19.39 
FROM (SELECT * FROM Gastos 
      INNER JOIN Tiene_gasto ON Gastos.id_gasto = Tiene_gasto.id_gasto
      INNER JOIN Usuarios ON Tiene_gasto.correo_u = Usuarios.correo WHERE Usuarios.correo = 'juan@lol') 
      AS Gast;
```

Pero me dice que tengo problemas en la sintaxis, tengo alunas horas programando y creo ya no veo los errores mas obvios ¿Alguien identifica algun problema de sintaxis?

> Error: Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'FROM (SELECT * FROM
>   Gastos
>         INNER JOIN Tiene_gasto ON Gastos.id_gasto = T' en la linea 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para hacer ese `UPDATE` en mysql no necesitas un `FROM`, tienes que poner `INNER JOIN` despues del `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE Gastos
INNER JOIN Tiene_gasto ON Gastos.id_gasto = Tiene_gasto.id_gasto
INNER JOIN Usuarios ON Tiene_gasto.correo_u = Usuarios.correo 
SET Gastos.monto = Gastos.monto/ 19.39
WHERE Usuarios.correo = 'juan@lol'
```

Comment: Era justo eso, mil gracias, tenia dias con ese problema.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta quitar el `select` y hacer directo el `from` de la tabla `Gastos`  ademas en la operación define que monto pertenece a la tabla `Gast`

Ejemplo:

```
UPDATE Gastos GastoUpdate
SET GastoUpdate.monto = Gast.monto/ 19.39 
FROM Gastos as Gast
INNER JOIN Tiene_gasto ON Gastos.id_gasto = Tiene_gasto.id_gasto
INNER JOIN Usuarios ON Tiene_gasto.correo_u = Usuarios.correo 
WHERE Usuarios.correo = 'juan@lol'
```

Comment: Sale el mismo error

Comment: puede ser que el problema esta dummy intenta con la tabla Gastos